# Bug in merging different profiles

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Yesterday I created a profile in Stack Overflow and asked a question. Today I asked a question on Unix as unregistered user. Then I logged in with my SO login and password but I don't see my last post at Unix... but in my network profile I see a link to Unix & Linux  site.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: A0001

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (2b5f277d1c)

Comment: Stack Overflow is abbreviated "SO". You need to fill out the merge user profiles form linked at the bottom of any page on UNIX under "contact us". In future, join a site **before** posting anything if you want everything on one account.